# How do I replace this old single switch that has 3 wires going to it?

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a switch next to my back door that controls 2 flood lights outside. I want to replace it with a different switch and when I pulled it I noticed it has a white wire attached to the switch. I'm not sure what to do here. The switch is next to a bank of 3 other switches, there is also an outlet below and a little to the right of the switch. There are 4 14/2 wires coming into the box. This isn't a 3 way switch as there is no other side that I can find. I'm assuming its a single pole switch, but I can't find one to replace it with that has 3 places to put these wires. Attached my best effort at a diagram of what is going on in the box and how it is connected to the existing light switch.

My best guess is the upper left two 14/2 wires are the light fixtures, the upper right seems to be the source of power, and the lower left seems to be a borrowed neutral from the outlet below maybe? What kind of switch do I replace this with? My single pole switches only have line/load and a ground. What is the white wire for going to the switch?
[image: wire diagram]

[image: switch_4]
[image: switch_1]
[image: switch_2]
[image: switch_3]

Comment: Switches do not use neutral, but might use white wires.  If a switch has three or more screws(not including green ground screw), then it should be a three/four way and have a second switch also controlling the lights.  The way you show the switch, means there is a second switch, find it.

Comment: Your best guess doesn't make sense. You need to verify the voltages with a multi meter.  Take  few pictures and post them into your question. Say hi to Mary.

Comment: Turn off the breaker.  pull the switch out from the box and take pictures of both sides showing the wires connected. Post the pictures in your question or a link to a picture site.

Comment: updated with pictures

Comment: that is a 3 way switch, go hunting for the other one

Comment: Turn off the breaker. Tag and remove the wires (so you can put them back in the same places, but using the screws and not the back stabs - back stabs are (a) unreliable and (b) designed to only be used once). Then use a multimeter to test continuity between the screws with the switch in different positions. I'll bet you find it matches a 3-way - i.e., one screw connects to another screw when "up" and to the other screw when "down". In which case, you need to find that other 3-way. Now that doesn't actually make sense because what is *supposed* to be the case is that with a pair of 3-ways you

Comment: have **3** wires (excluding ground) going between the switches **in a single cable** - either two travelers + hot or two travelers + switched hot or two travelers + neutral, but that is not always observed properly.

Comment: OK, i found the other switch! So, when i flip the switch on the other side none of the wires on this switch pictured are hot anymore. Is this expected or is something wrong with the other switch? Other switch looks like it was changed out before.

Comment: Think I got it sorted. On the other switch the white traveller was not connected to the switch but was grouped in the all the whites in the box.